# JavaScript target=_blank add undefined in the url

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have following anchor tag with `target=_blank` to open in new window but it was not opening.

```
<a target="_blank" href="/help" id="help-link" tabindex="-1">
    <i class="icons icon-help"></i>
    {{#EscapeExpression locale.widgets.actionMenu.help.label}}{{/EscapeExpression}}
</a>
```

I have tried it with javascript `onclick` like below;

```
<a target="_blank" onclick="window.open('/help')" id="help-link" tabindex="-1">
    <i class="icons icon-help"></i>
    {{#EscapeExpression locale.widgets.actionMenu.help.label}}{{/EscapeExpression}}
</a>
```

This opens link in a new tab but issue is while opening the tab it adds `'undefined'` and end of the url in the previous tab like this.

```
http://localhost:8080/console/dashboard/undefined
```

This result a blank page as router doesn't know about his `url`. Any help for fixing this issue?

Comment: Works fine for me -> [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z9MJw/).
Is there any event listener on your a - element? Would also be nice to see the rendered code.

Comment: @alexP it works in html, but its not working with my environment i.e. backbone. I think router has some issue with this...

Answer (score 0):

Below is the fix for the issue. This `onclick="window.open('/help','_blank'); return false;" href="#"` has fixed the issue for me.

```
<a onclick="window.open('/help','_blank'); return false;" href="#" tabindex="-1">
   <i class="icon-rp icon-help"></i>
   {{#EscapeExpression locale.widgets.actionMenu.help.label}}{{/EscapeExpression}}
</a>
```

Comment: Works in all browsers except windows phone (8.1) IE-11. seems windows.open has some issue with that.